# Google API 1.8.1 - Google Drive document commenter's PermissionId/EmailAddress

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a very simple code:

```
...
DriveService service = new DriveService(initializer);

CommentList comments = service.Comments.List(fileId).Execute();
...
```

As a result I get a list of comments (comments.Items property), in each comment there is an Author property having populated only "DisplayName" and a "Picture" properties.
"PermissionId" property is a null and I am confused how to retrieve permissionId or email address of the commenter?

Thanks in advance.